# setTimeout is not working when I pass a parameter into the function

Tags: javascript

I've decided to make a simple canvas game and I to change a Boolean variable to `false` (from `true`) after delay. I've made a simple function that looks like this:

```
var someVariable = true;

function changeBoolean(){
    someVariable = false;
}

setTimeout(changeBoolean, 1000);
```

. . . and it works perfectly. But my game is getting bigger and I don't want to make extra functions for every variable, so I figured out a way to do it like this:

```
var someVariable = true;

function changeBoolean(argument) {
    argument = false;
}

setTimeout(changeBoolean(someVariable),1000);
```

. . . and it doesn't work. Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass `setTimeout` a *function* to call.  That's what you are doing in the first example, you are passing it `changeBoolean` which is a function.

In the second example, you are *calling* `changeBoolean(someVariable)`, then passing its return value - `undefined` -  to `setTimeout`.

You can passing an *anonymous function* instead:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    changeBoolean(someVariable);
},1000);
```

This won't actually work though as `someVariable` will be passed by value, so all `changeBoolean` will see is `argument` being set `true` or `false`, but it won't know which variable outside had that value, so it can't change its value.

One solution could be to store your variable in an object, and just tell `changeBoolean` what *key* to change:

```
var variables = {
    someVariable: true
};

function changeBoolean(argument) {
    variables[argument] = false;
}

setTimeout(function(){
    changeBoolean('someVariable');
},1000);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast and excellent response. This is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that JavaScript is pass by value, not by reference. This means that by changing `argument`, you are not changing `someVariable`.

From a more technical perspective, JavaScript uses something called Variable Environment (think of a local scope) for variables in functions. The values from this environment will not be persisted to the Lexical Environment (think more globally scoped) once the scope closes.

JavaScript uses as stack of **[Execution Contexts<sup>ECMA</sup>](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.3)** in order to maintain its scoping, and if you would like more information about the structure of scoping that is a good place to start.

---

Scoping aside, as [@RocketHazmat points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43353727/settimeout-is-not-working-when-i-pass-a-parameter-into-the-function#comment73770859_43353793), in order for `setTimeout` to work, it needs to be passed a function to call. Your example code is passing the result of a function call, and there is no return value, so in essence this is just `setTimeout(undefined,1000)` which will not work.

Please see [Rocket's explanation in their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43353827/1026459) for a suggestion to call the setTimeout, it is essentially what I would place here.

Comment: That's *one* of the problems.  In his second example, the `setTimeout` is never passed a function for it to run.

Comment: That is true @Rocket, he is passing the result of the function (which is `undefined` to setTimeout. I will edit that in.